# C# How to read variable from list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a sample list.

```
            List<Reminders> remind2 = new List<Reminders>() {
               new Reminders() { Checked = true, Name_re = "Impreza" },
               new Reminders() { Checked = true, Name_re = "Impreza1" },
               new Reminders() { Checked = false, Name_re = "Impreza2" },
               new Reminders() { Checked = true, Name_re = "Impreza3" },
               new Reminders() { Checked = true, Name_re = "Impreza4" },
               new Reminders() { Checked = false, Name_re = "Impreza5" },
               new Reminders() { Checked = true, Name_re = "Impreza6" },
               new Reminders() { Checked = false, Name_re = "Impreza7" }
        };
```

And I have only one variable, for example "Impreza1".

How to read that for this variable Checked = true?

Comment: May I assume this is C#?

Answer (score 1):

if you just want a boolean result, use linq `.Any()` i.e.

```
var text = "Impreza1";
bool isChecked = remind2.Any(x=>x.Name_re==text && x.Checked);
```

if you want to grab the variable if it is true, try this:

```
var reminder = remind2.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name_re==text && x.Checked);
if(reminder!=null)
{
   //its checked..do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think LINQ makes this quite easy:

```
    List<Reminders> remind2 = new List<Reminders>() {
           new Reminders() { Checked = true, Name_re = "Impreza" },
           new Reminders() { Checked = true, Name_re = "Impreza1" },
           new Reminders() { Checked = false, Name_re = "Impreza2" },
           new Reminders() { Checked = true, Name_re = "Impreza3" },
           new Reminders() { Checked = true, Name_re = "Impreza4" },
           new Reminders() { Checked = false, Name_re = "Impreza5" },
           new Reminders() { Checked = true, Name_re = "Impreza6" },
           new Reminders() { Checked = false, Name_re = "Impreza7" }
    };
    var name = "Impresa";
    var checkedWithName = from rem in remind2 where rem.Name_re == name && rem.Checked select rem/*.ToList()*/;
```

In case you need a single `Reminders`, you can call `Single()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx) on the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = remind2.FirstorDefault(p=> p.Name_re.ToLower().Equals("Impreza1".ToLower());



bool checked = result.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't certain whether the item exists, but there should be no more than one:

```
var reminder = remind2.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name_re == "Impreza1");
if (reminder != null)
// Use the value of reminder.Checked
```

If you aren't certain whether the item exists, and there could be more than one:

```
var reminder = remind2.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name_re == "Impreza1");
if (reminder != null)
// Use the value of reminder.Checked
```

If you are absolutely certain there is exactly one item with the given Name, then:

```
var isChecked = remind2.Single(r => r.Name_re == "Impreza1").Checked;
```

But in the case where there is exactly one item per Name, you would be using the wrong data structure - storing your data in a `Dictionary<string, bool>` would be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another flavor (this is case sensitive though...) - For more you can check for example: 
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
//*** Find all occurences Given Checked value - If not found _results2.Count==0
//*** Here x.Checked.Equals is used for boolean value
List<Reminders> _results2 = new List<Reminders>();
_results2 = remind2.FindAll(x => x.Checked.Equals(true));

string _stringToFind="Impreza";

//*** Find 1 occurence Given Name_re - If not found: _result==null
Reminders _result = remind2.Find(x => x.Name_re.Contains(_stringToFind));

//*** Find all occurences Given Nmae_re - If not found _results.Count==0
List<Reminders> _results = new List<Reminders>();
_results = remind2.FindAll(x => x.Name_re.Contains(_stringToFind));
```